# How to download file from SFTP in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ssh

I am trying to use the classes in `Renci.SshNet.Sftp` to download a file from an SFTP server with VB.NET.  Here is my code:

```
Using client As New SftpClient("server", "test", "test")
    client.Connect()
    Dim list As List(Of SftpFile) = CType(client.ListDirectory(""), List(Of SftpFile))
    '------------------------
    For Each sFile As SftpFile In list
        Console.WriteLine(sFile.Name)
        client.DownloadFile("path", ????)
    Next
    client.Disconnect()
End Using
```

With this code I can connect to the server and see the file, but I can't download it. I don't know how to call the `DownloadFile` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter of the `DownloadFile` method takes a stream.  So, you just need to create a new `FileStream` to write the downloaded data to a new file, like this:

```
Using fs As New FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write)
    client.DownloadFile(serverFilePath, fs)
End Using
```